# Opencart 1.4 Incorrect image URLs in https

Tags: php, ssl, opencart

I don't have much experience with Opencart or php, so flying a bit blind here..
I have a customer who wants their Opencart 1.4.9.6 to be served over SSL, not a problem, except that for some reason, when viewing in IE on https, none of the images are showing up.

On doing some digging, it seems that just on https, the $baseurl used in the  tag in the head shows as https:///[my-domain].com, as do the product images.

It is fine when served on http. There was a redirect rule added to force SSL, I have taken this out to rule it out as that was a new addition, it still happens (yes I have cleared the cache..)

Has anyone had anything similar? I can fix the $baseurl issue by replacing /// with // when echoed on to the page, but that does not fix the images, and there's a lot more than just one of them..

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the HTTPS_Server variable defined in the admin/config.php file was being overwritten in the base index.php file by what looks like some custom code that was appending https:// to a url fetched from some other configuration, though why is unclear.

I got around the issue by cleaning the url before it gets redefined and that seems to have solved my woes.

Answer (score 0):

There is constant `HTTPS_SERVER` in the `config.php` and `admin/config.php` that you should change to right value. For example:

```
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://website.com/');
```

After changing those constants you have to turn on secure connection in administration side

Comment: Yeah, I saw that was in there.. but that was already correct.. Turns out, that is being overwritten on the base index.php page, getting the url from some kind of configuration and overriding what's in the config file whilst appending https:// to it. I got around it and will answer below..  Thanks for the pointer anyway..